# How do I find the average of specific cells in a .csv file from python?

Tags: python, csv

So basically, I would like to find the mean of specific cells inside of a .csv file from python. Essentially, the user should be able to input a difficulty (Easy, Medium or Hard) and then the program should look for the rows in the .csv that contain this inputted difficulty and then find the mean of the scores in those same rows.

For example, if the user inputs "Easy", then the program should output 2.5 as the mean score (as (2+3)/2 is 2.5).

Here's the code:

```
    file = open("Example.csv", "r")
    for line in file:
      details = line.split(",")
      which=input("Which topic would like? ")
      if which in details[2]:
        average = sum(details[0])/len(details[0])
        print(str(average))
```

Here's the text for the .csv file:

2,Jo12,Easy,Geography

3,Ste11,Easy,Maths

5,Jo12,Medium,Maths

3,Ste11,Hard,Geography

Comment: show me the code please? if not we cant help you and forced to closed this question

Comment: Go through this pandas tutorial: http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/urls/bitbucket.org/hrojas/learn-pandas/raw/master/lessons/01%20-%20Lesson.ipynb. And you will know how! Good luck!

Comment: @AbhishtaGatya I have just added the code, sorry about that.

Comment: A csv file is a **text** file containing field delimiters and some fields can be enclosed in quotes. So a spreadsheet image cannot help in knowing what the delimiter is, and if fields are correctly enclosed in quotes when it is required. So please show the actual csv file in text format.

Comment: @SergeBallesta just updated thanks

Comment: The contents inside the csv file and the code doesn't really make sense on what you are trying to achieve. please consider reading this https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch001356.htm to create a proper csv file and as for your code I suggest this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xi52tx6phRU&t=253s

Comment: @AbhishtaGatya I have updated the code slightly, let me know if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 0):

Until you are able to understand exactly how the interpreter will process your code, start with a paper sheet and a pencil and describe the algorithm *by hand*.

Here you want to get the average value of numbers in the first column when the value in third one is equal to a string asked from a user. Here is how I could describe the process:

- ask user for a topic name
- loop over the lines of the csv file

  - if the value of the third field is not equal to the topic name, continue directly on next line
  - else

    - add the value the a sum of values (initialy set to 0)
    - increase the number of values (initialy set to 0)
- if the number of values is 0, tell the user that the topic was not found
- else the average is equal to the sum of the values divided by the number of values.

Until your code is an implementation of a working algorithm like what is shown above, you will not get the expected result. Currently your code is close to non sense :-(

Comment: My problem is that I do not know how to describe the number of values in python in order to calculate the mean.Thanks for the help btw.

Comment: I have a somewhat working solution but still have no clue how to represent the number of values in python. Please help, thanks in advance